# Create New Message using Facebook Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to send Message using Facebook Graph Api.

I found this article http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

But still i couldnt find a proper api to create a new Message from my android app.

Can anyone please let me know whether, creating a new message is feasible ? Any tutorial or reference reg that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook API currently does not permit 3rd Party app to post messages to users (friends or otherwise) to prevent spamming.

This has been asked a few times here on SO. I have a few links added.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9047881/450534

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/291/ (Source: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/4525572/450534)

**NOTE:** There is a workaround, or so it seems, but I have personally never gotten around to trying it myself. See if any of the answers on the link after this bit helps you out.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/2943297/450534

Answer (score 2):

You can send a message by using direct url in which you have to provide your app id, friend user id whom you have to send message and redirect uri where you have to redirect page after sending message on Facebook.

```
var redirect_uri= you site url;
var sendUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=**app_id**&to=**friend_id**&picture=**imageurl**&link=**yoursitelink**&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri;
```

Hit sendUrl and send message..

Answer (score -1):

```
var redirect_uri= www.ibda3world.com;
var sendUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?387805884642610=**387805884642610**&to=**100001280661576**&picture=**https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1380084_637568089629207_126766341_n.jpg**&link=**www.ibda3world.com**&redirect_uri="www.ibda3world.com;
```

Comment: you would do better to add words describing what you are doing here and how it relates to the OP.

Comment: Please include at least a tiny description with your code. Code only answers are generally not considered "high quality"