# how can i send private message to Facebook user?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hai iam using facebook graph API to send message to facebook user and that is stored in the inbox but the message was not displayed. Is there any permission needed to post the private message when the user is online or offline,any idea or related links? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Go through this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483341/create-new-message-using-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [custom url scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825). In your case `fb://messaging/compose/1347150232`, where 1347150232 is the userid. This will open the **compose message** page on the facebook app for a given user.

See also the [Communicating with Other Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html):

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://messaging/compose/1347150232"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

Comment: I forgot the userid. Url should be fb://messaging/compose/1347150232, where 1347150232 is the userid in this example. Updated the answer.

Comment: @asgoth He wants to do it using graph API, your solution just opens the facebook application and lets the user input the message

Comment: Ah ok, I'll leave the answer open, since it could help somebody else.